# One or more integrations have been reset because of a change to their xml configs

Tags: magento2, admin

I have installed Magento2 in **AWS server**. After deploying, I get this warning message on top of admin dashboard.

> Warning : One or more integrations have been reset because of a change
>   to their xml configs

I checked in google, but no one has reported this error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TL;DR:  You should not worry about it. Ignore it and go on with your everyday life.

Long version:
Magento 2 comes with a new module called `Shopial_Facebook` that adds a new "integration" to the platform. Something facebook related...not important.
If one of the integrations (that you can find in System->Integrations) has the status RECREATED (int value 2) you will get this warning.
This RECREATED status is achieved when there is a change in the config settings of the integration. And this being new, of course there is a change in the settings.
So you can go on ignoring this message.

Comment: Still, this pops up on every admin page load. Cannot it be dismissed until another configuration changes?

Comment: not sure about it, but you can try to deactivate the integration. If the status is not rejected anymore you should not see the notification.

Comment: How to hide this message?

Comment: I've actually disabled the Shopial_Facebook module, i dont use it and it takes the message away. php bin/magento module:disable Shopial_Facebook

Answer (score 32):

It is very annoying though. For every admin page that loads, just as you are about to click on something immediately after the page loads, the whole page shifts down one row to display the error message. I've lost track of the amount of times I've clicked on something wrong because of this.

A warning should be there to notify the user of something that they need to be aware of. As far as I can see, this warning serves no purpose and is of no interest to the end user and shouldn't be displayed.

If like me, you have no interest in this module, it can be disabled as follows. Takes care of the constant warning message anyway.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Shopial_Facebook
```

"usability points"--

Comment: After disabling this module, I believe my Magento admin is faster. I won't double check it. Maybe it's something with that notification and possibly a 3rd party request in background. I just disable.

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix if you don't have SSH or just want to get the alert out of the way of the Admin Panel.

You can simply click on Magento Social activate link next to status and reactivate it. You may get a 404 error on the activate page but the annoying message will go away. Hope this help.

NOTE: I would use (Graham Wharton) method if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that adds requests to something called "ezsocialshop" without my permission or consent, branded as "Magento Social". That's a high price for getting rid of a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something database query seemed the quickest approach if it's something you don't want.

`UPDATE integration SET status=0 WHERE status=2;`

Backup the table before if you are unsure what you are doing.